# How do I get constants defined in my service using JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, annotations, jax-ws

I have a webservice that I'm using JAX-WS annotations to generate the WSDL & associated client code (writing both ends, just using JAX-WS for the transport).

I've got a method that can have different return values depending on the state of the request,

```
@WebMethod
public int uploadResults( 
        @WebParam(name="authentication") ServiceAuth auth, 
        @WebParam(name="mimeType") String mimeType, 
        @WebParam(name="data") byte [] dataBlock )
{
  // ... omitted.
```

and some return values are also defined in the class.

```
public static final int STATUS_OK = 0;
public static final int STATUS_ERROR = 1;
public static final int STATUS_AUTH_FAILURE = 2;
... etc.
```

After using wsgen to generate the WSDL, and wsimport for the client-side code, there aren't any references anywhere to these constants.  Ideally, I'd rather not define them in two spots, and they don't share a source tree, so it's also a little awkward to define them in a common location.

**So, my question is**:
Is there an annotation I could put on each of the declarations so that something would be written with the identifier into the WSDL and subsequently, a similar constant defined in the client-side classes generated by wsimport?

(p.s. I'd also appreciate any comments on 'you're doing it wrong, return status this way instead...')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you be better off trying to pass exceptions down the wire then coming up with a custom way that needs to be defined in two areas?

Comment: Well, not all the statuses are error conditions, and the purist in me dislikes the idea of throwing an exception to indicate "Everything was great, but...".

Comment: Almost like you would be better off returning an enum or something like that.  I think returning complex objects is tough, but if they are objects of simple types, you'd be okay.  I seem to remember that you have to create a data contract for the enum and then it will be placed into the wsdl.  I know you are asking for a specific annotation, but I can't think of it right now.

Comment: I'm giving up on this; I'll give you the full rep since you were the only one nice enough to answer.  :-)  Thanks.